# Alternatives to making _id mass assignable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I've got a spec for a rails controller, that tests creation of a associated model:

Models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  attr_accessible :foo, :foo_id
end
```

The controller spec:

```
@foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
expect {
  post :create, { bar: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:bar, foo_id: @foo.id )}
}.to change(Bar, :count).by(1)
```

If I change this Spec to the form where I don't have to make `foo_id` mass-assignable, it breaks with `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch expected Foo got String`:

```
@foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
expect {
  post :create, { bar: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:bar, foo: @foo )}
}.to change(Bar, :count).by(1)
```

and

```
describe Bar do
  it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:foo_id) }
end
```

The Controller code is quite simple:

```
def create
    @bar = Bar.new(params[:bar])
    if @bar.save
      redirect_to @bar
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to make the spec run without making `foo_id` accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FactoryGirl `.attributes_for` ignores associations. You can do

```
FactoryGirl.build(:bar).attributes
```

however that way you need to delete unwanted params like `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, etc.

I suggest you to create a special method in `spec_helper`:

```
def build_attributes(*args)
  FactoryGirl.build(*args).attributes.delete_if do |k, v|
    ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'].member?(k)
  end
end
```

and then use it: `post :create, :bar => build_attributes(:bar)`.

Comment: This is a very big step in the right direction, but it looks like this approach still requires the `foo_id` to be mass-assignable?

Comment: no, you should add to your controller's create action: `@bar.foo = foo` before saving `@bar`

Comment: If I'm doing this I need to delete the `foo_id` attribute in `params['bar']` which the helper method created in the first place?

Comment: yes, if you protected it from mass-assigment. you need to delete it in `build_attributes` helper, not in controller.

Comment: Didn't think that there isn't a more elegant solution to this, thank you very much!